# Putting spaces in weird places

Tags: php, regex

I'm debugging the following code:

Input: `FOO || BAR BAR`

```
<?php
 echo preg_replace('/([^|]*) |/', '$1', 'FOO || BAR BAR') ?>
?>
```

Output: `FOO|| BarBar`

I want to just delete the preg_replace expression because the input is what I want anyway. But I assume it's been coded (by another dev) for a reason.

Can you explain what the RegExp is doing, so that we can guess why it's there?

Comment: 1: by the input and output, the title of the question is wrong. 2: the code after this should help understanding why it's done - say it explodes the string in spaces or whatever. Check what's done with the variable after the regex.

Comment: The regex removes all spaces form the string, that are no direct successors to a pipe. Anyway that pipe (regex or character) at the end of the regex mask makes no sense at all.

Comment: The old dev can't say himself.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear.

In case you want to understand, what the regular expression is actually looking for, I suggest online regex tools, e.g. [Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/S7Wuxj/1) (already pre-filled with your example code).

If you want to understand the "why" of that code snippet, you would need to examine the code afterwards just like FirstOne suggests in his comment.

From what I see, I guess there is an error in the regular expression. I assume, the original intention was to delete the space character in front of the pipe character. However, the pipe character is a special character in regular expressions (logical OR), so it would need to be escaped:

```
<?php
 echo preg_replace('/([^|]*) \|/', '$1', 'FOO || BAR BAR') ?>
?>
```